# Is there a fast way of drawing characters to the screen?

Tags: c#

I developed a Matrix themed application in Java, and was experimenting with porting to over to C#. However, I found that the latter's `DrawString` method offered much poorer performance when drawing lots of single characters. Thus I'm hoping there exists one of two possibilities:

1. There is an alternative method of drawing lots of single characters that is much faster.
2. There is a way to draw a string with fixed spacing to achieve the same effect. This does not seem likely.

Does anyone know of any way to accomplish either 1 or 2?

Additional information:

- I need to be able to draw around **20000 characters 30 times per
  second**.
- The characters can have the same font and size, but colour should be able to be
  altered.
- The set of characters is finite (letters, numbers, and punctuation).
- The location of the characters are along a 2D grid, and do not overlap.

Comment: How fast do you need?

Comment: All characters are of the same font, size and styling?

Comment: What did you use in Java? 30 million characters per second is quite a lot!

Comment: 30 million characters per second, is this done in Java? I dare not believe. And how big is your screen? How can it hold such bunch of chars which are also legible?

Comment: Yah, I realized it was a bit crazy. I was thinking of pixels instead of characters. Slight difference, ha.

Comment: @ZongLi, would you mind expanding just a little bit on the background of your app?

Comment: Have you tried WPF? WPF when used properly is fast. Otherwise Direct2D? there is wrapper for .NET here: http://direct2dsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: Are you building a Matrix animation? I suspect you're building a Matrix animation. A Matrix animation is cool. I like Matrix animation. Try Googling "C# Matrix animation", bet you can find some useful tips in other people's code.

Comment: @David I've done the exact same thing, I coded it in Java first, then wrote the exact same code and style in C#, Java runs smoothly but c# flickers like there's no tomorrow at half the speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an alternative method of drawing lots of single characters that is much faster?

The [`Graphics.DrawString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) methods use GDI+ to draw, which tends to be slower than GDI. GDI is usually hardware accelerated, assuming you have a decent set of graphics drivers installed. The only exception to this is Windows Vista with the Aero theme enabled, but that was fixed in Windows 7. You can switch to GDI instead by calling one of the [`TextRenderer.DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext.aspx) methods instead. Not only is that likely to be somewhat faster than GDI+, there are other advantages to using GDI. The only real disadvantage is that WinForms doesn't support using GDI for printing. But it doesn't sound like that's a concern for you.

Assuming you're targeting only modern versions of Windows that support them, you could also look into some of the new graphics technologies like Direct2D and DirectWrite. For C# wrappers, you might look into the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) (also see [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/directx/archive/2009/08/13/managed-wrappers-for-the-directx-apis-in-windows-7.aspx)). OpenGL might also be an option. I haven't used it, but speed is among its claims to fame.

Unfortunately, I'm still not sure if this will be fast enough. A million characters 30 times per second is really an unreasonable amount. No video output device that I know of is even capable of displaying this. Surely there is some type of caching that you could be doing instead. Or perhaps an entirely different design for your application?

Also, keep in mind that drawing into a background buffer (e.g., a bitmap) is often considerably faster than drawing directly onto the display buffer (i.e., the monitor). So you can do all of your drawing onto this background buffer, then periodically blit that to the screen in a single pass. This technique is often known as "double-buffering" (because it uses two buffers), and is a well-known tactic for minimizing flicker. It can also produce speed improvements if you need to draw as quickly as possible, because it allows you to do so while taking into account the inherent limitations of the display output.

> There is a way to draw a string with fixed spacing to achieve the same effect. This does not seem likely.

Drawing with fixed spacing is not going to increase the speed over using proportional spacing.

There *are* a few "tricks of the trade" to keep in mind when you're writing particularly critical drawing code, but I seriously doubt that these will be of much use to you, given how high you're expectations are. They're more for tuning an algorithm, not increasing its performance by multiple orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of some blazing fast alternative, but using GDI([TextRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ftkekek.aspx)) instead of GDI+(DrawString) will give a better result. Up to 5-6 times faster.

[GDI vs. GDI+ Text Rendering Performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/05/19/602021.aspx)

Another useful article - [Rendering fast with GDI+ - What to do and what not to do!](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/66909/Rendering-fast-with-GDI-What-to-do-and-what-not-to)